# How to Setup tempfs/RAM Disk (Generally and for LuaLaTeX)?

Tags: partitioning, ram, latex, tmpfs

I've spent the past several hours (not few, several!) reading different pages and questions on how to setup a tmpfs/RAMDisk. They all say different things and say what filesystems I should and shouldn't be including, so I would really appreciate a conclusive, updated answer on this.

I have 16GB of RAM and I want to dedicate maybe 6-8GB to a RAM disk.

1) I plan on adding `/tmp`, `/var/cache`, and `~/.cache` to the RAM Disk (and Firefox through `profile-sync-daemon`). Any other suggestions on what to add? I read on moving `/var/lock` and `/var/run` too, but since it's from `/var` is that advisable?

2) I run LaTeX a lot (LuaLaTeX specifically) so I was thinking maybe I could install that in the RAM instead of on the actual SSD and see if that runs faster? Or I could move `/var/lib/texmf` and `~/.texmf-var` to RAM? I don't know, so I'd appreciate the advice!

Comment: @psusi ??? I specifically linked to that question and stated why I'm asking about it "again"...

Comment: They don't explicitly create a ramdisk; they create a directory in which to mount it, and then mount it ( which creates it ).

Comment: You should ask for clarification on an existing answer as a comment there rather than creating a whole new question.

Comment: The two answers don't explicitly create a ramdisk? I've seen in some answers to other questions where it's not even mounted, the appropriate line is simply entered into `fstab` and then rebooted. So the `mkdir` and `mount` lines do need to be entered then?

Comment: Also I don't have enough reputation to post a comment there; I feel that an answer should be an answer and not asking for clarification as it would appear messy, hence why I asked here.

Comment: fstab just specifies what should be mounted automatically during boot.  To mount something you have to have somewhere to mount it, hence why they created a new directory since it they didn't already have an existing directory they wanted to mount it in.

Comment: @psusi Thanks for clarifying, appreciate it! :) I still am wondering about the last 2 questions I posted here; should I post those separately or leave them here (would that still make this entire question a duplicate then?)?

Comment: Go ahead and remove the first part instead of striking it out ( it's just distracting ) and then the two remaining questions would be unique.

Comment: @psusi just to clarify, when you create `/media/ramdisk` (for example) and want to add `/tmp` and other filesystems to ramdisk, don't you have to mount `/tmp` (and others) to `/media/ramdisk`? So in the second answer [from this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152868/how-do-i-make-a-ram-disk) you would do the first two lines (`mkdir` and `mount` the `ramdisk`) and then add `/media/ramdisk /tmp tmpfs noatime,nodev,mode=1777 0 0` to `fstab`? That's why I got confused about mounting or simply editing `fstab`; once `ramdisk` is created where does `/tmp` go get mounted??

Comment: No.  You don't mount one directory to another.  Normally you mount a block device into a directory, but since tmpfs is a ramdisk, the block device argument is ignored.  Again, the only reason they created /media/ramdisk is because they didn't have some other place, such as /tmp that they wanted to make a ramdisk.  Again, you don't "create" the ramdisk, and then mount it; you just mount it and it springs into existence to satisfy the mount request.

Answer (score 2):

/var/run is tied to the specific running instance of a machine at a time due to storing PIDs of the running processes, I would only avoid placing that on a RAM disk if you are using a virtual machine and suspend the VM often.  /var/lock is intended to prevent more than a single instance of a given application from running and thus should also be fine.  If you have a service which is not well behaved and uses the leftover pid/lock files to detect crashes you should either relocate the paths they store the information or find alternatives.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html

There are estimates running applications on a RAM disk may result in performance [increases of in the 10x range](http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk).  The bandwidth between your process and memory is definitely faster on modern AMD64 systems, thus this claim has substance if you are IO bound somewhere between the CPU and the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a quick question, I did `sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk` and then `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=4G tmpfs /media/ramdisk/`. After doing `grep /media/ramdisk /etc/mtab | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`, the file `fstab` does include the `/media/ramdisk` as part of it. So how do I add `/tmp` and the other folders?? `/media/ramdisk` has nothing in it right now so why did I even make this directory? How do I add multiple folders (`/tmp`, `/var/run`, etc) to ramdisk?

Comment: You would need to replace the target files {/tmp,/var/run,etc} with symbolic links using a combination of the `rm` and `ln` commands (IE: `rm /tmp && ln -s /media/ramdisk-tmp /tmp`).  I would recommend creating a separate RAM disk for each area you wish to replace.  This allows control of the size for each group, as `/tmp` should be larger than `/var/run` and `/var/lock`.  Another approach would be to setup a startup script to create the directories within the RAM disk