# Preload most-used piece of software

Tags: ram, cache

I tried an in-memory Linux distro and I was shocked by how fast it was.

Is there is a way to always cache in memory some (user specified) software like the file explorer so that you can benefit of that speed without having to preload the whole system in the memory (unfeasible if it's your main desktop because there would be not enough memory)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a RAM disk in Ubuntu, and then copy your preferred program on it, and run it from RAM.

See for example here how to create a RAM disk :

[How do I make a RAM disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152868/how-do-i-make-a-ram-disk#152871)

You could create a bash script for this, which you can load after boot time, for example with a crontab entry :

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/my-RAM-disk-script.sh
```